# How complete is the financial statement data?

Tags: curated-data, finance, entity

Has anyone here looked at `CompanyData` or `Entity["Company",All]`?

Are both of them the same data but just a different interface to access them?

Looking at all the available entities

```
CompanyData[]//Short
EntityList[Entity["Company",All]]//Short
```

and all the available properties

```
CompanyData["Properties"]//Short
EntityProperties[Entity["Company",All]]//Short
```

both seems to hold the same structure. Are they the same dataset underneath?

Moreover is the data complete, i.e. is one able to build all four major financial statements (Balance Sheet, Income Statement, Cashflow Statement and Statement of changes in Equity) atleast the annual ones in detail and reconcile them (Does the created balance sheet balance)?

How far back does the data go?

Is there a way to look at the sources being used for each entry?

Previously I have been relying on EDGAR database but since this data is already curated with units, it seems like a more attractive option if it is complete and reliable that is.

Comment: `CompanyData` and `EntityValue` do give access to the same information - the `XXXData` functions (such as `ElementData` or `BridgeData`, etc) are the older interface, and `EntityValue` is newer.  If you run `TracePrint[
 CompanyData["Mars::d48zc", "TotalRevenue"],
 _EntityValue
 ]` you can see that `CompanyData` just calls `EntityValue`.  I can't speak to the rest of the question though.